# Dependency Injection in ZF2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

In my application i get product list through an api request. For listing the product in each and every page i need to perform the same api request each and every time with userid as parameter.  This will increase the server load, so to avoid this i need to get product list and reuse the instance.

How can i implement this with a single call by introducing DI  or Dependency Container.

Or is there any other technique to accomplish this ? i don't want to use session or database

Comment: DI is entirely the wrong mechanism to consider for this problem.
DI is simply the act of injecting a dependancy ( $thing = new Thing($dependancy) or $thing->setOtherThing($dependancy) ), and has nothing to do with saving you server load. 
A DI Container, is simply a magic black box which will perform those operations for you, and still will not reduce any server load, and infact with a badly implemented container, will increase it.
What you should be looking at, is Caching, as in the one answer currently attached to this question, which will result in reducing the number of webservice requests

Comment: Or is there any other mechanism to accomplish this ?

Comment: how to define dependency container as singleton in zf2. How and where to initialize ? The above scenario is just an example. With a single  client connection how can we restrict the connection once established. For  example if we are requesting for a db connection the connection should be made as singleton per client. Caching is for data. i am talking about the connection established or let say objects created

Answer (score 1):

The good approach is to use cache. For example:

```
// your service
public function getProducts($id)
{
    if ($cache = $this->cache->hasItem($id)) {
        return $this->cache->getItem($id);
    }

    // call api
    $result = $this->api->call($id);
    $this->cache->setItem($id, $result);

    return $result;
}
```

For cache instance you can use Zend\Cache